# Mirror directory between windows hosts

Tags: windows, synchronization

I'm looking secure way to one-way mirror directory between windows hosts over the internet.

Host A - Has directory with files. Should run some sort of server on single open port X. Everything else is blocked at firewall level that I don't have access to. (Tried to use Filezilla FTPS server but passive mode data-connection would not initialize, because everything else is blocked).

Host B - Windows Scheduled task should run every 5 mins some sort of client program to connect Host A and download new files (and changed files). (First thought was to use lftp.exe with mirror option)

Files are small log files.
What would be most stable and preferably freeware/opensource solution for this?

Comment: Is this in a corporate network in which you are an administrator? How come you have the limitation of the single port?

Comment: Host A is embedded device somewhere in remote outpost.

Answer (score 0):

VPN tunnel between the servers to create a secure connection.

Use [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=15155) to synchronise the files, using an Echo relationship. This can be ran as a scheduled task.

Comment: Having no previous experience with VPN tunnels - are they stable and do they auto establish, in case tunnel disconnects?

Comment: Yes they are stable and yes they can auto reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean something like `rsync`.

Usually you call it like

```
rsync -a --delete src destination
```

(careful with --delete: it removes all files from the destination no longer found in src)

In this case you'd put a scheduled task on host A to update the destination B. But you can also use B and pull files from a using this method I guess.

I believe there are rsync ports for Windows.

Run like this to do a simulation

```
rsync -avn --delete src destination
```

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, GoodSync would do this quite well (it now have a server option), but it is not free (and you would probably need two licenses in this case).

Another relatively easy to understand solution is to setup a webserver and configure it to serve on that port. You can use IIS if your Windows version have it or Apache/nginx if you're able to configure it. There are many client options for this, you can use web-archievers or some scripting with wget/curl. Alternatively, you can install WebDAV on the web server and mount a drive over http(s). Most sync tools (or similar) will be able to work with the web mount like normal local drive.

A third-option is to run OpenVPN and you'll have a full-access connection via VPN; however, OpenVPN is most fiddly to configure.

Another option is SSTP VPN which requires a copy of Windows Server 2008: you just need to setup the system HTTPS listener to be on that specific port. (This configuration is however not supported by M$.) All other VPN types requires other ports and protocols to pass through the firewall.

If you're courageous, you can also look at IPv6 NAT-traversal solutions, but additional security consideration will be necessary.